# ADWORDS Universal App campaign: 'new playstore app not shown in app list'

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-ads-api

I have just uploaded a new app on the play store, the app shows in the store and can be downloaded; everything works fine but when I try to create a universal campaign on AdWords, I cant find the app on the list of apps on the android app store.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about app stores are considered to be off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)

Comment: the question is about adwords as a service. playstore just happens to be one of the party involved

Comment: Regardless, your question is not about programming. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more about what sorts of questions are suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that recently published apps will take a while to appear in Adwords Universal App Campaign (mine took at least 48 hours after the app was officially available for download on the store). I also discovered that I had not completed some parts of the app listing and the app was listed as a beta version on Playstore at the time I had this issue: which may or may not be the cause.

Generally; you should be looking out for how long since you published the app on the store and also; if there are outstanding information you need to provide to google play.

Comment: It took less than 24 hours for me

Comment: yes, @ByteArtisan. the timing varies and I guess as the days go by, Google improves their services and maybe things can happen faster.